# IE9 position:fixed object appears and disappears intermittently

Tags: html, css

So my mark-up is a little something like this:

```
<div id="stage">
    <div id="stageHeader">
        <h1>header text</h1>
        <a href="#"><img src="something.png" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
    <p> blah blah blah content blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JsUW3/

I have the contents of the `#stageHeader` set to a fixed position so that as the over all stage fills up and allows for scrolling these objects stay in place. All works great and they do not move at all in any browser including IE.

The interesting thing is that in IE9 if I scroll down the page, the contents of `#stageHeader` will appear and disappear but not move.

On certain other parts of the application you wont see the `<h1>` at all but if you move the mouse around it will intermittently appear but then disappear again.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on here. I have checked the z-indexes of all the surrounding elements to see if something is covering it up or something small along those lines but have had no success. There isn't really anything in my JavaScript that would affect it either, and it only occurs in IE9 and only when set to `position:fixed`.

Comment: I've copied the code from your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUW3/) into the question and formatted it to make it a little easier to read. As I mentioned in your other question, if you are going to use http://jsfiddle.net then you really need to recreate the issue, rather than just linking to it with empty markup. It will be much easier for us to help you if we can actually see the issue you are referring to.

Comment: I appreciate you editing/formatting the question to make it easier to understand. When I get a stable build of my application up and running I will provide a link to it directly in order to give a true example.